# Formula Won't Stop Skipping Lines When Writing Data

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I'm currently working on a project using Google form to gather data into an excel sheet, and then organize the data based on answers of the form. After an employee selects a department and submits a form, I would like to filter each response by department to its own page within the workbook.

I've listed my current formula below. As of now, it will only import the data on the same row when it is sorted into a new page, thus leaving many blank spaces in between information. Is there a way to make sure it will not skip rows during the import?

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH('Form Responses 1'!D2:D1101, "Department Name"), 'Form Responses 1'!B2:B1101," ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER('Form Responses 1'!B2:B1101, 
 REGEXMATCH('Form Responses 1'!D2:D1101, "Department Name"))
```

Comment: This works like a charm, thanks so much! I've accepted your response as the answer. Best Regards!